# List comprehensions for Sum square difference

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Could you explain, please, why it doesn`t work well?

```
print([sum(a)**2 for a in range(100)] - [sum(a*a) for a in range(100)])
```

I am trying to solve [image: Euler problem 6] in one line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Python_DevOps/hw/hw9.py", line 15
    print([sum(a)**2 for a in range(1,100)] - [sum(a*a) for a in range(1,100)])
  File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Python_DevOps/hw/hw9.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    print([sum(a)**2 for a in range(1,100)] - [sum(a*a) for a in range(1,100)])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You need to move the `sum` terms to outside of the list comprehensions.  E.g.  something like this: `sum([a**2 for a in range(100)])`

Comment: ```sum``` receives an iterable as argument. You are providing an integer which is not iterable. So a ```loop``` should be ```inside``` the ```sum``` parenthesis

Comment: what is your expected answer

Comment: Also, `-` is not defined as an operator between 2 lists

Comment: Your answer should be something like ```print(sum(a for a in range(1,11))**2 - sum(a**2 for a in range(1,11)))
```

Comment: See my answer, it explain all the part and even proper that given in comment ;) Alsso read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write `sum(a)` and `sum(a*a)` none of them sums multiple values, you need to sum all the values you build in the list comprehension

```
sum([a ** 2 for a in range(100)])
```

Then `a**2 == a*a` so your actual would give 0, the first argument is the square of the sum, you can directly pass the `range` to the `sum` as it expects an iterable

```
i = 11
print(sum(range(1, i)) ** 2 - sum(a ** 2 for a in range(1, i))) # 2640
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in python `sum` receives an itterable(in this case a list) not an integer, so you should simply add the comprehension in the sum's parenthesis.

**like so:**

```
>>> print(sum(a**2 for a in range(100)) - sum(a*a for a in range(100)))
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

Comment: Try it, it isn't that ;) As advice for a few-year member : **always** try your code before posting it, i would avoid mistake ;)

Comment: I id in python shell like always I ma not a newbie

Comment: There is not need to create a new list. ```sum``` already receives parameters as iterables

Comment: Really ? Because your code gives a nice **0** ;)

Comment: sorry mixed up code snippets, Its an honest mistake

Comment: ... did you seriously **NOT** fix the code and change to a **0** that is NOT what the question ask for ? A code that always return 0 isn't very usefull `print(0)` does same ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum):

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total.

So when you do `sum(a)`, `a` is an integer which has be generated by the `range()` function. Since integers are not iterable, it raises a type error.

Also, `a**2` is equal to `a*a` so you output would be zero. The answer according to the question is something like:

```
print(sum(a for a in range(1,11))**2 - sum(a**2 for a in range(1,11)))
```